# Type or Name Space not found

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to use the following code from COPL and i get an Error Type or namespace Combinations not found. Can any one Please help me with this.I am unable find a assembly reference or a namespace associated.

```
char[] inputSet = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

Combinations<char> combinations = new Combinations<char>(inputSet, 3);
string cformat = "Combinations of {{A B C D}} choose 3: size = {0}";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cformat, combinations.Count));
foreach (IList<char> c in combinations)
{
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{{0} {1} {2}}}", c[0], c[1], c[2]));
}
```

Comment: Where is `Combinations` class defined?

Comment: what is COPL? What is `Combinations` type?

Comment: That is what i am unable to find

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Its likely that you are using this piece of code without referencing an assembly that has this type.

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on.  Can you give a link to the site where you got this code?

Comment: I found the link (see my answer below) at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is copied/pasted from this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

It is a test example of how to use one of the classes in an assembly, for which the code is also provided (follow the 'Download' link).

In order to make the test code work, you need to download their code, build it, and put a reference to the generated assembly into your own project.

Comment: Ahh, he/she meant CPOL (Code Project Open License)

Comment: When you say 'research', you mean 'two minutes on Google'? If only life were always this easy ...